# Trying to get chromedriver to work but seem to have an outdated version that is not compatible with the latest chrome, any ideas to fix this?

Tags: java, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111

tried running my test scripts but they won't run given the error above

Comment: Update chrome driver or downgrade chrome? What is unclear about the error message? Did you check [ask]?

Comment: Google updated their browser to 116.0.5845..111 but failed to update the chromedriver to the same version. 
At the moment the only change is to downgrade Google to .96 and install the chromedriver from here https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip